# How to make an if then else if control structure as an expression (in a nice way)

Tags: haskell

I was wondering the correct and elegant way to do such a thing

```
function candy = case (color candy) of
    Blue -> if (isTasty candy) then eat candy
            else if (isSmelly candy) then dump candy
            else leave candy
```

I tried

```
function candy = case (color candy) of
    Blue -> dealWith candy
        where dealWith c
                | isTasty c = eat candy
                | isSmelly c = dump candy
                | otherwise = leave candy
```

Anyone knows how to improve on this?

**MORE**

I know I can use this

```
function candy = case (color candy) of
    Blue -> case () of
                _ | isTasty candy -> eat candy
                  | isSmelly candy -> dump candy
                  | otherwise -> leave candy
```

But using a `case` while not matching anything just doesn't seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use guards directly in your outer `case` expression.

```
fun candy = case color candy of
    Blue | isTasty candy  -> eat candy
         | isSmelly candy -> dump candy
         | otherwise      -> leave candy
```

Comment: I went with your approach in the end. However, would like to know the answer to why having a function defintion in where doesn't work

Comment: @yulan6248: It works fine here. You are allowed to have a `where` clause on each alternative of a `case`, and they are shared between guards, just like on a function. See [the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) for details.

Comment: Thx, my bad, it's an indentation problem. I'm a super-newbie to Haskell and bear with me for asking silly questions

Comment: What is that construct called?  We beginners learn that the clauses of a case look like: pattern1 -> result1

Comment: @7stud: I don't know if there is an accepted name for it. You can probably call them "guarded case alternatives" or "guards in a case expression". You can see [the whole syntax for `case` expressions defined in the Haskell Language Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13).

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Multi-way if-expressions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) in GHC 7.6:

```
fun candy = case color candy of
    Blue -> if | isTasty candy -> eat candy
               | isSmelly candy -> dump candy
               | otherwise -> leave candy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a table-like structure using tuples. I've been known to do this:

```
function candy = case (color candy, isTasty candy, isSmelly candy) of
  (Blue, True, _   ) -> eat candy
  (Blue,    _, True) -> dump candy
   _                 -> leave candy
```

Comment: This is an interesting construct; although a bit redundant in this case. Also, you can't use this if you have arbitrary boolean functions to evaluate

Comment: What do you mean "arbitrary boolean functions"?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was wrong, it does deal with most situations. I guess the negative then is you need to write a long list tuple if you have lots of predicates to evaluate

Comment: Ideally in that case, you would create a datatype to represent the possibilities and use [view patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) to simplify the structure.